# Moving Servers but Keeping Older Versions of PHP, Apache, etc

Tags: linux, centos

Old Server
CentOS 5
PHP 5.2.14

New Server
RHEL 6
PHP 5.2.14

Thus far, I've been compiling PHP 5.2.14 from source which has worked fine but now I'm realizing installing php-devel from rpm will ask to upgrade PHP.  What's the best way to move to this new RHEL6 server but maintaining the PHP 5.2.14 version along with the extensions?  I know I can't use the default RPM repo.

Comment: Don't move? Don't stay on an ancient version of PHP?

Comment: You haven't explained why you need to continue using an unsupported version of PHP.  You can download the latest 5.3 and first try compiling with the same configure command you use with 5.2

Comment: Per the dev, upgrading to 5.3 will break "stuff."  I'll have to see what was deprecated.

Comment: ultimately it will be better to fix the "stuff" than to keep using outdated unsupported software.  maybe not today but sooner or later you will have compelling reason.

Comment: I concur and that is my recommendation just doing my homework and having a backup plan.  Let's see if other people have recommendations and I will close out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's *MUCH* easier for yourself if you'd stick with RPMs instead of compiling from source as going forward you'll need less of your own time to maintan it. RHEL6 comes w/ PHP 5.3.x yet RHEL5 is 5.2.x., but if you really want to go that route, you'd need to recompile everything again since you're moving up some of major libraries and just by coping files over most likely won't work.

Comment: Pedantry: RHEL5 is 5.1.6, but also offers 5.3.3 as `php53`. The poster is referring to a custom build.

Comment: ah, that's new) last time I checked they were only offering 5.2 for RHEL5 and 5.3 for RHEL6, I guess they finally backported it. either case it's much better going with RPMs then compiling from a source

Comment: And what if I absolutely need 5.2.14?  I know going RPM would be easiest but I might not have a choice.

Comment: @Michael In the Debian (`apt`) world there is "pinning"; YUM has "[priorities](http://wiki.centos.org/PackageManagement/Yum/Priorities)" which appears to be similar but YMMV.

Comment: @Michael you can try to build your own RPMs using rpmbuild, but honestly PHP 5.4.x is very big improvement over previous release especially 5.2, I'd strongly advise you to go with latest and not legacy.